# Is it possible to find by expression using the mongo find function?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Say I have data like this:

```
{
  a: 2,
  b: 1
}
```

I want to find all the values where a is greater than b.

I can obviously do this using the **aggregate pipeline**, or using **$where**, but can I do it using the plain old find function? It feels like it ought to be possible to do this, as I would in the aggregate pipeline:

```
db.collection.find({
  a: {
    '$gt': '$b'
  }
})
```

*(this doesn't work)*

Is this not supported, and if not, is this by design, philosophy or omission? Alternately, am I just being an idiot?

Comment: I don't think that MongoDB supports expressions that accommodate comparison between two or more fields other than the [**`$where`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/#considerations) expression or the aggregation framework which uses the same query language as regular find. The best you could do is store in your document a denormalized flag, like `isGreater` that stores the boolean `(a - b > 0)`. There is a similar JIRA for this here [SERVER-7623](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-7623).

Comment: Planned but not scheduled. Thanks @chridam, that was the answer I was looking for. I ask because it feels like an inconsistency. If you write this as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that MongoDB yet supports expressions that accommodate comparison between two or more fields other than the **[`$where`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/#considerations)** expression or the aggregation framework which uses the same query language as regular find.

The best you could do is store in your document a denormalized flag, like `isGreater` that stores the boolean `(a - b > 0)` which you can then query with the `find()`

```
db.collection.find({"isGreater": true})
```

There is a similar JIRA ticket for this here **[SERVER-7623](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-7623)** which is planned but not scheduled.

Comment: `7623` is actually older than the introduction of `$redact`. In fact, since `$redact` supports this type of logic it should be reasonable to say that "issue" is a "non-issue". Use `$redact`.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree @BlakesSeven. If an API is supplied, and that API appears inconsistent, it should either be fixed, deprecated or clearly signposted. Code desires perfection.

Comment: @superluminary You seem to be on a campaign here to argue against things that work as has been noted in your recent questions. So we really don't have to agree with you either. But you "should" be learning from those who know rather than have a preconceived "I think it should be like this" notion.

Comment: @BlakesSeven - I'm not on a campaign, and I'm not arguing against anything. Aggregation is beautiful, I love it and use it every day. If you read my question more closely though you will see why $redact is not the correct answer here.

Comment: @BlakesSeven - I should also point out that I'm not attacking Mongo or you. Mongo is brilliant, and you seem nice enough. I apologise for any appearance to the contrary. Text is a thin medium.

Comment: @BlakesSeven - I feel rather like I'm stepping into a warzone here with my moderately innocent Mongo questions. I know Mongo has taken some heavy flak from the SQL crowd. Is that the cause of the hostility?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [**`$redact`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/) operator.

```js
db.collection.aggregate(
    [
        { "$redact": {
            "$cond": {
                if: { "$gt": [ "$a", "$b" ] }, 
                then: "$$KEEP", 
                else: "$$PRUNE"
            }
          }
        }
    ]
)
```

Comment: It's an easy problem with the asset pipeline. I could also use $match. I'm wondering if it's possible using plain old find(). It looks like it should be possible. My inability to get it tow work using find suggests I'm either being a moron, there's some philosophical issue I'm not aware of, or it's a missing feature.

Comment: No you can't use find. and you don't want to use `$where` because it does not take advantage of indexes

Comment: @superluminary `$redact` does not use indexes either. But it should process faster than JavaScript evaluation.

Comment: @BlakesSeven - This is true, though I was explicitly wondering if this is possible without the aggregate framework, as it appears it ought to be.

Comment: @superluminary What is wrong with it? This does a "logical" comparison betwen two field values ( what you asked for ) without needing to run interpretted code as JavaScript evaluation does with `$where`. This means it's "as fast as it can possibly be". There is no syntax for `.find()` that does this. And this is not "slower" than `.find()` (which can only use JavaScript evaluation here). So this "is" the "native" way to do this. You seem to have walked in with some preconceptions that you probably should loose.

Comment: Hi @BlakesSeven - I never said it was slower, and there is nothing wrong with it, it just appears to be inconsistent with find. My (moderately extensive) experience with software development has taught me that where I encounter an apparent inconsistency, it's usually me that's in the wrong, not the world. Why would aggregation behave one way, and the find convenience wrapper behave in this entirely other way? The answer appears to be: "Just because", which I hope you'll agree is wholly unsatisfying.